# Exception not thrown, when error occurs on second sql insert/update statement

Tags: hibernate, jpa, grails, jdbc, grails-orm

We have the problem, that our app does not throw SQL-Exceptions in some cases.
This happens when the error occurs on the second or later insert/update statement. This behavior is described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/367).

We only get a log-entry like: `ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Transaction was deadlocked on resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.`

Is this issue fixed in one of the newer versions of hibernate? Or has anybody an idea, how we can patch this?

We are using:

- Grails 2.5.6
- Hibernate 4.3.8
- Hibernate JPA: 2.1

Example: `myObject.save()` creates 2 insert statements. One into the base-table and one into a foreign-table. The second insert causes the error, which should result in an exception.

Code example:

```
class Children {
    Parent parent
    String name
}
class Parent {
    static hasMany = [children: Children]
}

@Transactional
void save() {
    Parent parent = new Parent()
    parent.addToChildren(new Children(name: 'Bob'))
    parent.save() //more then 1 insert is executed
}
```

Comment: have you tried to run each query in a separate transaction?

Comment: The ORM creates the insert/update on its own. There is an insert into the base-table and a insert into a foreign table. This needs to be in one transaction.

Comment: edit question and show the code

Answer (score -1):

'Children' must have the 'belongsTo' closure for the call to save() of  'Parent' to cascade the save also to 'Children'.

```
static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]
```

ref : http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#gormAssociation

Comment: The cascading is not the problem. In cases of deadlocks of further (cascaded) insert statements there is no exception thrown. That is our problem.